# Creating a User Interface From a Data Model

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcdatamodel

I already created my xcdatamodel file. Then I follow instruction in

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeCoreDataTools/Articles/xcdCreatingUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006854-SW1

So I created a new project. I select iOs Application Window Based Application.

Then I follow the instruction of option dragging the entities into the main view. Nothing happens.

What should I do?

Any video tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the documentation. From what I know it is not possible to do this with iOS (ie Cocoa Touch) projects, it only works with Mac OS (ie Cocoa) programs.

from the document:

> You can use the Xcode modeling tool to quickly create a user interface for managing entity instances in a **Cocoa** application.

Comment: Ah I see. Cocoa binding is not available at IOS

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem to work for a MAC OS application either. It look like there is a bug in Xcode 4 or the function has been removed.